# Extracting matches from php regex

Tags: php, regex, perl

In perl regex we can extract the matched variables, ex below.

```
   # extract hours, minutes, seconds
   $time =~ /(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/; # match hh:mm:ss format
   $hours = $1;
   $minutes = $2;
   $seconds = $3;
```

How to do this in php?

```
$subject = "E:contact@customer.com I:100955";
$pattern = "/^E:/";
if (preg_match($pattern, $subject)) {
    echo "Yes, A Match";
}
```

How to extract the email from there?  (We can explode it and get it...but would like a method to get it directly through regex)?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try using the named subpattern syntax of preg_match:

```
<?php

$str = 'foobar: 2008';

// Works in PHP 5.2.2 and later.
preg_match('/(?<name>\w+): (?<digit>\d+)/', $str, $matches);

// Before PHP 5.2.2, use this:
// preg_match('/(?P<name>\w+): (?P<digit>\d+)/', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);

?>
```

Output:

```
 Array (
     [0] => foobar: 2008
     [name] => foobar
     [1] => foobar
     [digit] => 2008
     [2] => 2008 )
```

Answer (score 11):

Check the php [manual](http://be.php.net/preg_match)

> int preg_match  ( string $pattern  , string $subject  [, array &$matches [, int $flags  [, int $offset  ]]] )
>
> If matches  is provided, then it is filled with the results of search.
>   $matches[0] will contain the text that
>   matched the full pattern, $matches[1](http://be.php.net/preg_match) 
>   will have the text that matched the
>   first captured parenthesized
>   subpattern, and so on.

```
$subject = "E:contact@customer.com I:100955";
$pattern = "/^E:(?<contact>\w+) I:(?<id>\d+)$/";
if (preg_match($pattern, $subject,$matches)) {
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The simpler solution

1. go to [regex101.com](https://www.regex101.com)
2. Use the great documentation for creating and testing your regex (make sure you select PHP).
3. In the ***TOOLS*** section click on `code generation`
4. This is an example of what I got.

```
$re = '/\#.*@hello\((?<operator>\w+),?(?<args>.*)\).*/m';
$str = ' Testing string
# @hello(group_fields)
# @hello(operator, arguments, more arguments)';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the matchs parameter of the preg_match function as follows:

matches:

 
If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern, $matches[1] will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You can just modify your current regexp to capture everything after the colon up to the first space:

```
$subject = "E:contact@customer.com I:100955";
$pattern = "/^E:([^ ]+)/";
if (preg_match($pattern, $subject, $m)) {
    echo "Yes, A Match";
}
$email = $m[1];
```

In case you're not familiar with regexp, `[^ ]+` means *"any character but a space"* and it doesn't require a space to be present to work. If for any reason the input changes to *"E:email@host.tld"* without the *" I:12345"* bit, it will still work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct `function` to find! But you can have your own `function`s like these:

```
function preg_find($pattern, $text, $def = null){
    $matches = PREG_FindAll($pattern, $text);
    return isset($matches[0])?$matches[0]:$def;
}

function preg_findall($pattern, $text){
    preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);
    return $matches;
}
```

Enjoy...