# How to extract words from a string that end with substrings listed in an array?

Tags: php, filtering, substring

How is it possible to print all words from a string with ends with specific letters like for example:

```
$words = "lernen spielen betteln lachen example"; 
$EndsWith=['en','eln'];
```

In this example should everything be printed except of the word example.

I only know how to find the characters with `substr`, but this works only for one the last word in a string.

Comment: Have a look at regexes. Here is a [useful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492980/extracting-matches-from-php-regex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regex like:

```
([A-Za-z]+(?:en|eln))\b
```

to find words ending in `en` or `eln`, assuming you consider a word to only have alpha ascii characters. You can modify the character class to encompass more "word" characters.

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/7i5iS8/1/

PHP usage:

```
$words = "lernen spielen betteln lachen example"; 
$EndsWith=['en','eln'];
preg_match_all('/([A-Za-z]+(?:' . implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $EndsWith)) . '))\b/', $words, $words_that_end);
print_r($words_that_end[1]);
```

The [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) here is incase any values in `$EndsWith` contain a reserved regex character, for example `.`. If you pass a `.`  into a regex that characters means any single character that is not a new line, whereas you really wanted a literal `.`. In regex it must be `\.` or `[.]`; this function does that for you (it does the `\.` syntax).

If all the characters in `$EndsWith` are always alpha you don't need that function. The demo below shows a usage not using it.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/deBUD

This answer also assumes `en` and `eln` are not words on their own.

Comment: faster pattern - no alternatives: `/[a-z]+el?n\b/` (of course, not build dynamically from array.)

Comment: @mickmackusa The first regex is just to demonstrate it compiled. I don't know what the actual values will be. If this is literal and not an MVCE I agree the optional would be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string into an array using [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php).

`$words = preg_split('/\s+/', 'lernen spielen betteln lachen example');`

This will produce the array:

```
Array (
    [0] => lernen
    [1] => spielen
    [2] => betteln
    [3] => lachen
    [4] => example
)
```

From there you can iterate over the array, and checking each word if it ends with one of the `$endsWith` elements.

```
$wordsThatEndWith = [];

foreach ($words as $word) {
    foreach ($endsWith as $endWith) {
        if (substr($word, -strlen($endWith)) === $endWith) {
            $wordsThatEndWith[] = $word;
        }
    }
}
```

`$wordsThatEndWith` will now be an array with all the words that end with any of those elements:

```
Array
(
    [0] => lernen
    [1] => spielen
    [2] => betteln
    [3] => lachen
)
```

Comment: `preg_split()` is an expensive choice for this task because all of the spaces in the input are single spaces.  For this reason, explode() is the wiser choice.

Answer (score 0):

Explode the string by spaces to get each word separately, then iterate over then and check if it ends in something in the array.

```
$words = explode(' ', $words);
foreach($words as $word) {
    foreach($EndsWith as $end) {
        if(substr($word, -strlen($end)) === $end) {
            echo $word;
        }
    }
}
```