# How to make regex with this format "image(numeric, string)"?

Tags: php, regex

i want to make regex to detect this format `image(numeric, string)`. ex: `image(100, 'test')`.

i have tried this one, but just detect the `image(numeric)`

```
/image\((\d+)\)/
```

Any help with second parameter and the `,`?

Also how i can get the second parameter?

Comment: use `\w+` for sec pera

Comment: Does your text always have single quotes?  Could it have double quotes?  What about no quotes at all?

Comment: Oh sorry, just single quote :) @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: just like example.

Comment: can you give me example @Bhargav ?
actually i dont know how to add the `, 'test'`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following pattern:

```
/image\(\d+,\s*'.+?'\)/
```

I removed the capture group since it would be not needed if using the regex for validation only.

### Demo

If you want to capture the number and text, then use capture groups:

```
$input = "code image(123, 'meh') more code";
if (preg_match("/image\((\d+),\s*'(.+?)'\)/", $input, $m)) {
    echo "match";
}
$number = $m[1];
$text = $m[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
image\((\d+), '(.+?)'\)
```

The `.` matches anything and the rest is pretty much self-explanatory. Group 1 is your number, group 2 is the string.

Comment: How to get the group 2? @sweeper

Comment: I don't in fact know much about php. This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492980/extracting-matches-from-php-regex @MuhGhazaliAkbar

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
image\(\s*\d+\s*\,\s*'.*'\s*\)
```